# Prove that $\overrightarrow{AB}\cap \overrightarrow{BA} = \{A,B\}\cup \{X: A-X-B\}$

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry

As far as I can tell, both of these are perfectly sufficient definitions for a line segment $\overline{AB}$. The book I am using defines them the latter way, but is the first definition also equivalent?

If so how would I prove that these sets are in fact the same?

In other words how would I prove $$\overline{AB}:=\overrightarrow{AB}\cap \overrightarrow{BA} = \{A,B\}\cup \{X: A-X-B\}$$

EDIT: $A-X-B$ reads $X$ is between $A$ & $B$.

In other words, $A$, $B$, & $C$ are collinear and $\overrightarrow{XA}\cap \overrightarrow{XB} = \{X\}$

Comment: What does $\{X: A - X- B\}$ mean?

Comment: @Randall I edited in the definition.

Comment: In your text, is $\overrightarrow{AB}$ considered to be a certain point-set?  If not, then $\overrightarrow{AB}\cap \overrightarrow{BA}$ is nonsense.  Classical geometry is often done without referring to point-sets.

Answer (score 0):

According to my definitions

$\overrightarrow{AB}=\{A,B\}\cup\{X\colon  A-X-B \vee A-B-X\}$ and $\overline{AB}=\{A,B\}\cup\{X\colon A-X-B\}$.

Hence the inclusion $\overline{AB}\subset\overrightarrow{AB}\cap\overrightarrow{BA}$ is obvious.

For the opposite inclusion you only need to know that

$P-Q-R \implies R-Q-P$ and
$P-Q-R \implies \neg Q-P-R$,

in other words betweenness is symmetric and at most one of the three points is between the other two. Both these propertries are usually taken as axioms in axiomatic systems.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: For example, Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries: Development and History by  Marvin Jay Greenberg.